# Flutter Riverpod call StateProvider within a class that itself is a StateProvider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a `Class` that is being called by `Widgets` but this `Class` needs to pull data from another  `Class`.  Basically, I am using Riverpod as Dependency Injection, and am unsure if this is "correct" or am I doing it wrong. Here is what I did:

**`main.dart`**

```
var myClass1 = Class1();
final class1Provider = StateProvider((ref) => myClass1);
final class2Provider = StateProvider((ref) => Class2(myClass1));
```

Is this the recommended way or should I do something else?

FYI this does work;

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  displayData = (ref.watch(class2Provider.notifier).state).getData();
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is incorrect. You are using riverpod but are mixing it with global variables which trashes the whole point of using a state-management library.

1. You should create instances inside the StateProvider:

```dart
final class1Provider = StateProvider((ref) => Class1());
```

2. In order to access the value of one provider in another you need to use `ref.watch()` method inside the body of the provider:

```dart
final class2Provider = StateProvider((ref) {
  final myClass1 = ref.watch(class1Provider);
  return Class2(myClass1);
});
```

3. Finally, to consume a StateProvider you are watching the notifier instead of the state. This will give you an initial value correctly but will not rebuild your UI when the state changes. Instead you should watch the provider directly.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final displayData = ref.watch(class2Provider).getData();
}
```

For more info read the docs thoroughly https://riverpod.dev/docs/getting_started/.